# Are all images in Rigify documentation for Blender 2.79 valid for Blender 2.82 and 2.83?

Tags: rigify, documentation

Today (March 4, 2020), I compared the Rigify official documentation for the following Blender versions :

A) 2.79 (https://wiki.blender.jp/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify),

B) 2.82 (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html?highlight=rigify)

C) and 2.83 (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html?highlight=rigify)

These Rigify official documentations are exactly the same for Blender 2.82  and 2.83, and they are missing all the images, compared to version 2.79.

Question : Are all the images in https://wiki.blender.jp/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify valid for Blender 2.82  and 2.83 ?

Comment: Due to the new UI in Blender 2.8x and development on rigify the screenshots don't match the current appearance.

Comment: Unfortunately much of Blender Documentation is lacking in quality.  Its a choice. Maybe an opportunity to experiment and feel .....  If you are looking for lots of game show style promotional videos ... fortunately  you will find them.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger It's certainly not intentionally, but simply the result of limited time and having to rely on the contribution of volunteers.